# Error when training AllenNLP adversarial bias mitigator using a pretrained masked language model

Tags: python, json, bert-language-model, allennlp, mlmodel

I'm attempting to create an adversarially debiased bert masked language model using 'AdversarialBiasMitigator' alongside the AllenNLP pretrained MLM (from here: https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/bert-masked-lm-2020-10-07.tar.gz).
The training data I am using is a variation of the WinoBias dataset, edited to work for masked language modelling. The format of this data is a pandas df, with the first column containing the sentences (which already contains [CLS], [SEP], and [MASK] tokens), and the second column containing the target (which is a gendered pronoun).
I have edited the masked_language_model_reader.py to correctly read in my pandas df, and I have edited the adversarial_bias_mitigator config file. The remaining files (adversarial_bias_mitigator.py and masked_language_model.py) I have kept the same, so I think the source of the error must be either in the config or the mlm dataset reader I have created.

The main changes I have made in the dataset reader are changing the tokenizer to PretrainedTransformerTokenizer, and editing the _read() method to the following:

```
    @overrides
    def _read(self, file_path: str):
            import pandas as pd
            data= pd.read_csv(file_path)
            targets = data.iloc[:,0].tolist()
            sentences = data.iloc[:,1].tolist()
            zipped = zip(sentences, targets)
            for t, s in zipped:
                    sentence = s
                    tokens = self._tokenizer.tokenize(sentence) 
                    target = str(t)
                    t = Token("[MASK]")
                    yield self.text_to_instance(sentence, tokens, [target])
```

The rest I have kept virtually the same as the original masked_language_model_reader.py (https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/aed4876f04a73c7effddf41b3164e1fb6fb6c275/allennlp_models/lm/masked_language_model_reader.py). I know the above isn't very pythonic but it is the simplest way I could think of, and my dataset isn't that large (only 1000 sentences) so I don't think it is a problem of computing time.

When running all the relevant files in the CLI, the below error appears:

> 2021-10-02 10:52:20,351 - INFO -
> allennlp.training.gradient_descent_trainer - Training 0it [00:00,
> ?it/s] loading instances: 0it [00:00, ?it/s] loading instances: 162it
> [00:00, 1616.98it/s] loading instances: 324it [00:00, 1545.78it/s]
> loading instances: 479it [00:00, 1524.23it/s] loading instances: 681it
> [00:00, 1713.15it/s] loading instances: 1049it [00:00, 1764.63it/s]
> 0it [00:00, ?it/s] 2021-10-02 10:52:20,959 - CRITICAL - root -
> Uncaught exception Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/bin/allennlp", line 8, in 
> sys.exit(run())   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp/**main**.py", line
> 46, in run
> main(prog="allennlp")   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp/commands/**init**.py",
> line 122, in main
> args.func(args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py",
> line 121, in train_model_from_args
> file_friendly_logging=args.file_friendly_logging,   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py",
> line 187, in train_model_from_file
> return_model=return_model,   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py",
> line 260, in train_model
> file_friendly_logging=file_friendly_logging,   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py",
> line 504, in _train_worker
> metrics = train_loop.run()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py",
> line 577, in run
> return self.trainer.train()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp/training/gradient_descent_trainer.py",
> line 750, in train
> metrics, epoch = self._try_train()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp/training/gradient_descent_trainer.py",
> line 773, in _try_train
> train_metrics = self._train_epoch(epoch)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp/training/gradient_descent_trainer.py",
> line 490, in _train_epoch
> batch_outputs = self.batch_outputs(batch, for_training=True)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp/training/gradient_descent_trainer.py",
> line 383, in batch_outputs
> output_dict = self._pytorch_model(**batch)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py",
> line 1071, in _call_impl
> result = forward_call(*input, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp/fairness/adversarial_bias_mitigator.py",
> line 121, in forward
> predictor_output_dict = self.predictor.forward(*args, **kwargs)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp_models/lm/models/masked_language_model.py", line 110, in forward
> embeddings = self._text_field_embedder(tokens)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py",
> line 1071, in _call_impl
> result = forward_call(*input, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp/modules/text_field_embedders/basic_text_field_embedder.py",
> line 103, in forward
> token_vectors = embedder(**tensors, **forward_params_values)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py",
> line 1071, in _call_impl
> result = forward_call(*input, **kwargs) TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tokens'

I can't seem to work out what the problem is. I can't understand why being passed 'tokens' would be a  problem? I'm wondering if it the way I am reading in the data and if it isn't correctly being formatted into an instance, but again, I can't seem to see an obvious problem with my method in comparison to the original script as well.
To try to fix the problem I have also added into the config:

```
    "token_indexers": {
              "bert": {
                "type": "single_id"
              }
```

as well as:

```
    "sorting_keys":["tokens"]
```

I'm not sure if either of these things are related or helping/worsening the problem!

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tokens'`

The name of the field in your dataset reader should match the name of the field that the model is expecting. You can check the `forward` function of the model to get the correct field name.